# Image Texture box mapping - offsetting vectors on opposite sides?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, vector-mapping

Lets take a cube for example. I put an Image texture on it with box mapping on. It all works well, but one thing I notice is that the opposite sides are using the exact same position of the texture, which makes sense of course.

**However is there a way to offset the vector(s) so that the textures on opposite sides would be using the different position of the texture?**

I tried offsetting using Geomtry: Normal data thinking that I could offset each vectors with the Normal data (-1.0 to 1.0), but I haven't had any success with this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Geometry > Normal* socket is the way.

If you separate the vector components with a *Separate XYZ* node you can use the desired axis as mask for combining whatever you like (colors, textures, even shaders).

Use use the desired axis as input for the *Factor* socket of a color mix node. Then plug whatever you want on each color input. In your case just use the same image texture node with different vector input for coordinates.

With a *Vector Mapping* you can transform it however you see fit independently.
I added an additional *Vector Mapping* node because the *Normal* output of the *Geometry Node* is in Worldspace, meaning if you moved or rotated the mesh it would always point to the same global side.

[image]

The image illustrates the same cube object viewed from different sides in two separate viewports.