# Pokémon Eye Blink

Tags: materials, image, vector-mapping

Okay, I am brand new to Blender, and I am trying to teach myself to animate Pokémon during lockdown out of shear boredom. I'm using version 2.92, and finding tutorials for stuff on the latest version is apparantly really difficult.

I have managed to figure out most things from old tutorials, however, I cannot fathom how to get the eyes to blink.

I know it's a 2D Array, and I need to Vector Map the image to move to a different segment of the image - the issue I have, is I have no idea where in the program they have hidden this function.

I have found some stuff that might be it in the Materials tab, some stuff in the Shading Node Editor, some stuff in the Compositing Node Editor... but no matter what I try, when I attempt to alter the mapping of the image, instead of the new eye type, I get a red rectangle, or a black rectangle, or a teal rectangle. I didn't want to have to ask such a noobish question here, but I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days now, with no luck.

Comment: Hello, and welcome, please add some screenshots of the issue to show what you did and the result you are having.

Comment: I suspect you'll want the UV Editor (a tab at the top of the Blender UI at least in my v2.90). Also, I recall from when I animated Pokemon models that the open-eye UV map is contained on the main head mesh, and the planes containing the eye (which are remapped to the closed eye) are stored behind the eyes and moved to the surface or swapped positions with the open eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to review your image for the eyes and find out the blinking eye is. Then you follow the steps @Winry88628 did.

Basically what he did is that he offset the coordinates of eye UVs. The values in Mapping determine how much you need to move the UV, in terms of X Y and Z. The values vary from model to model. But normally you move them 2.5m for each set of eyes (for Pokemon models from 3ds)

After you placed the UVs correctly, you can make an animation using keyframes. For example, if your UV offset is 2.5m on X axis, on the start of the animation, insert keyframe at 0m and about 20 keyframes later insert another keyframe at 2.5m. Do remember to also insert a 0m keyframe BEFORE AND AFTER the blink keyframe, so instead of the UV moving slowly from 0 to 2.5 in 20 keyframes, it will move in 1 frame only, which makes your model look like it is actually blinking.

Here's an example of what I did:
[image]

[image]

1st rhombus: Eye Open (0m)   Keyframe 1
2nd rhombus: Eye Open (0m) Keyframe 18
3rd rhombus: Blink (2.5m)  Keyframe 20
4th rhombus: Eye Open (0m)  Keyframe 22

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Okay, I managed to figure it out, but I'm not sure I can explain it. I used this other post: [Image Texture box mapping - offsetting vectors on opposite sides?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105271/image-texture-box-mapping-offsetting-vectors-on-opposite-sides)

Through much trial and error, I ended up getting what I needed. Hopefully Image will provide help for anyone else that wants to do this.

Comment: Thanks to Nintendraw, whose mention of the UV Editor prompted me to try the action that resulted in the solve.